# How can I make a numbered section with the CSS counter skipping a header?

Tags: html, css, html-heading, css-counter

I am working on a page where I want the headings to have a section number. But skipping the first h3 header and giving that the value "(0.0.0)"

**Example:**

> ```
> Heading 2 (1.0.0)
>   Heading 3 (0.0.0) <- This one needs 0.0.0 (Skip the first h3 on page)
>   Heading 3 (1.1.0) 
>       Heading 4 (1.1.1)
>       Heading 4 (1.1.2)
> Heading 3 (1.2.0)
>       Heading 4 (1.2.1)
>       Heading 4 (1.2.2)
> Heading 2 (2.0.0)
>   Heading 3 (2.1.0)
>   Heading 3 (2.2.0)
>       Heading 4 (2.2.1)
>       Heading 4 (2.2.2)
> Heading 3 (2.3.0)
>       Heading 4 (2.3.1)
> ```

**I have already tried some things:**

```css
h1 {
  counter-reset: section;
}

h2 {
  counter-reset: subsection;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

h2::after {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: " (" counter(section) "." counter(subsection) "."
    counter(subsubsection) ") ";
}

h3::before {
  counter-increment: subsection;
}

h3 {
  counter-reset: subsubsection;
  padding-left: 150px;
}

h3::after {
  counter-increment: subsection;
  content: " (" counter(section) "." counter(subsection) "."
    counter(subsubsection) ") ";
}

h4 {
  padding-left: 250px;
}

h4::after {
  counter-increment: subsubsection;
  content: " (" counter(section) "." counter(subsection) "."
    counter(subsubsection) ") ";
}
```

```html
<h1>Test</h1>
<h2>Heading h2</h2>
<h3>Heading 3 (0.0.0)</h3>
<!--^ skip this one ^-->
<h3>Heading 3</h3>
<h4>Heading 4</h4>
<h4>Heading 4</h4>
<h3>Heading 3</h3>
<h4>Heading 4</h4>
<h4>Heading 4</h4>
<h2>Heading h2</h2>
<h3>Heading 3</h3>
<h3>Heading 3</h3>
<h4>Heading 4</h4>
<h4>Heading 4</h4>
<h3>Heading 3</h3>
<h4>Heading 4</h4>
```

I was wondering how I could do this or if there is anything I could look at.

*Side note:*
I also noticed that I am repeating code if there is a way to prevent that that would be great.

[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/StefvdPoel/pen/yLPEveQ)

Comment: The reason I want the first h3 header to be 0.0.0 is because it's called rule zero

Comment: If you give that h3 some class (like f.e. `special`), then you can exclude it from all the other places where you increment / reset the counter, by inserting a `:not(.special)` - https://codepen.io/CBroe/pen/GROGQBQ (Your second h2 heading still has a wrong count of `2.0.2` in there - but that was the case with your version already, so that is probably a separate issue to fix.)

Comment: Thanks this did solve the 0.0.0 but now indeed the other issue. Maybe it's because it increments in the h2 and not before let me test that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
h1 {
  counter-reset: section;
}

h2 {
  padding-left: 50px;
  counter-reset: subsection subsubsection;
}

h2::after {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: " (" counter(section) "." counter(subsection) "."
    counter(subsubsection) ") ";
}

h3:not(.RuleZero)::before {
  counter-increment: subsection;
}

h3 {
  padding-left: 150px;
}

h3:not(.RuleZero) {
  counter-reset: subsubsection;
  counter-increment: subsection;
}

h3:not(.RuleZero)::after {

  content: " (" counter(section) "." counter(subsection) "."
    counter(subsubsection) ") ";
}

h4 {
  padding-left: 250px;
}

h4::after {
  counter-increment: subsubsection;
  content: " (" counter(section) "." counter(subsection) "."
    counter(subsubsection) ") ";
}
```

```html
<h1>Test</h1>
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
<h3 class="RuleZero">Heading 3 (0.0.0)</h3>
<h3>Heading 3</h3>
<h4>Heading 4</h4>
<h4>Heading 4</h4>
<h3>Heading 3</h3>
<h4>Heading 4</h4>
<h4>Heading 4</h4>
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
<h3>Heading 3</h3>
<h3>Heading 3</h3>
<h4>Heading 4</h4>
<h4>Heading 4</h4>
<h3>Heading 3</h3>
<h4>Heading 4</h4>
```

[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/StefvdPoel/pen/wvPXyxE)